# Install scale in R

Tags: r, installation, scale

I try to install scale in R by:

```
devtools::install_github("scale",username="hadley/scale")
```

But

```
Downloading github repo hadley/scale/scale@master
Error in download(dest, src, auth) : client error: (404) Not Found
In addition: Warning message:
Username parameter is deprecated. Please use hadley/scale/scale
```

Comment: It should be `devtools::install_github("hadley/scales")`, with scale**s**.

Comment: Note that the latest version of the `scales` package (v0.2.5) is now also on CRAN. So you might simply try `install.packages("scales")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The general syntax of `install_github` function is:

`install_github(repo)`

where `repo` is in the format *"username*/*repository"*

2. The syntax of both *username* and *repository* should be checked, to avoid the message

> Error in download(dest, src, auth) : client error: (404) Not Found

3. It is also a good practice to compare versions available on both GitHub and CRAN. In the case of identical versions available, the simplest would be:

`install.packages(pkgname, dependencies = TRUE) # pkgname is enclosed in quotes`

where `dependencies` argument ensures the installation of all packages which `pkg` depends on/links to/imports/suggests.